# How to disallow cussing with Discord API

Tags: javascript

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var noSwear = require('./swear.json');
// Main prefix for all commands
var prefix = '!';
var swear = noSwear;



bot.on('ready', ready => {
  console.log("Initialized SwearJar")
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    var messageValue = message.content;
    if(messageValue.indexOf(["cuss", "swear", "cuss"])) {
      message.delete();
      message.author.sendMessage("No swearing!!!");
    }
    console.log(messageValue);
});
bot.login('###################');
```

The problem is whenever I type in the chat input box I get that message deleted and a private message sent saying "No swearing!!!" even with just typing "happy" or "F"

If there is a better way than .indexOf I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: usually you use `indexOf` like this: `if(messageValue.indexOf(["cuss", "swear", "cuss"]) > -1) {` when you want it to pass. Also I'd `split` the message as well, `var messageValue= message.content.split(' ');` then iterate through each index.

Comment: Hey Rob, unfortunately your method didn't really help me get to where I was going I was just using the array as an example I actually have a big array in another file named swear.json so instread of `if(mesageValue.indexOf(['']) > -1) {` it would be `if(messageValue.indexOf([noSwear]) > -1) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (noSwear.find(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
    message.author.sendMessage('Please do not use words like ' + message.content + ' that')
    message.delete()
  }
});
```